# JQuery $.post doesn't like datatype parameter

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

I am trying to make a JQuery call to a PHP script that is returning a JSON multi-row data set. When I use `$.post`, the call doesn't get made:

```
$.post("my_query.php", {search_filter: "the search text"}, function(data, status) {
           alert(data);
},"json");
```

When I leave the fourth parameter out, it works, but it returns everything in one row.

Using `$.ajax` works, so it's not a problem on the PHP side:

```
$.ajax({
    url : "my_query.php",
    type : "POST",
    data: {search_filter: "the search text"},
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data, status) {
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

This has only been tried on the latest version of Firefox.

Is there some bug with `$.post`, possibly limited to certain browsers?

Comment: That's very odd beaviour. For reference can you show us the responseText

Comment: Instead of using `alert` you should try to use `console.log()` to get it more close.

Comment: I have a feeling the responses are misunderstanding the problem. It appears that the call itself isn't being made, as if there's an error in the code - not that the call is made but is returning an error of some sort.